# Open an axes into a separate figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have created a GUI with several axes containing plots. I want to add a button which opens these plots in a separate figure so I can do some manipulation such as changing the title and saving it. It's not necessary that the axes update with the figure.

In other words, how can I export an axes of a GUI to a figure (separate window)?

This is my button callback which should open up the new figure

```
function btn_open_force_sandheight_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

axes(handles.force_sandheight); % This axes already contains the plots
```

Just to be clear, the plot already exists in the axes. I need to open it in a separate figure.

Answer (score 1):

See [copyobj()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html):

```
# Make a dummy "GUI"
h.fig1 = figure;
h.ax1 = axes('Parent', h.fig1);
plot(1:10);

# Spawn new figure window and copy axes object from the GUI
h.fig2 = figure;
h.ax2 = copyobj(h.ax1, h.fig2);
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what you are doing? I don't quite understand. My axes is called `handles.plot1` and is accessed inside a function callback for a button

Comment: @Ortix92 From the documentation the two inputs to `copyobj` are the object you want to copy, your axes, and the new parent object, a new figure window. Modify the handle names to match what you have in your function.

Comment: @Ortix92 all the `axes` call does in your edit is change the `CurrentAxes` to `handles.force_sandheight` and bring the window into focus, nothing is copied. If you want to open a new window you need to use `figure` and then you can copy your axes object into it, similar to what I did in the example.

Comment: Hmm strange because I did what you said but I get an empty figure..
`plots = getappdata(0,'plots');
h.fig2 = figure;
h.ax2 = copyobj(plots, h.fig2);`

Comment: @Ortix92 That's not what I said. I said use your existing axes handle, `handles.force_sandheight`. What is `plots`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66935/discussion-between-ortix92-and-excaza).

Comment: Plots contains the axes handle. I tried both ways; accessing the handle from within the callback simply with `axes()` and by using `setappdata()` and `getappdata()` by setting it after the plots are generated and getting it in the other callback. I wasn't sure if accessing the handle directly would work. But either way, it gives me an empty figure.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple! just change the property `'Parent'` of the axes to the new figure.

Example:

```
fh1 = figure('Name','1');
plot( rand(10) ); 
ah = gca; %// get handle to current axes in figure 1
```

Now we create a second figure and move the plot to it

```
fh2 = figure('Name','2');
set( ah, 'Parent', fh2 ); %// that's it!
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The axes is in the GUI. I don't want to change the parent. I want a copy of that axes inside a new figure